# Convergence of a sequence of functions.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, metric-spaces

I have a sequence of functions given by $f_k(x):\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f_k(x)=\sqrt{k}x^k(1-x)$. I wish to show that the largest set that $\{f_k\}^\infty _{k=1}$ converges pointwisely is $(-1,1]$.

Furthermore, I wish to show that within this same interval for $x$, convergence is not uniform.

Finally, I want to show that it IS uniform in any interval $[\lambda,1]$ for $\lambda \in (-1,1)$.

---

For the first part, I simply want to show that $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}f_k(x)=f(x)$. I'm going along the lines of $$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt{k}x^k(1-x)=(1-x)\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt{k}\times \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} x^k=0,$$ if $x\in (-1,1)$. If $x=1$ then the result that $f_k(x)=0$ is trivial.

For the second part I want to show that $lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}(sup_{x\in (-1,1]}d(f_k(x),0))\neq 0$. Thanks to Sharkos, I see as $x \rightarrow -1, |f_k(x)|\rightarrow 2\sqrt{k}.$ Hence as $k \rightarrow \infty$, uniform continuity is clearly not present.

For the third part I'm kinda stumped since I can not get my head around the second part.

Thank you all in advance for your help !

Answer (score 1):

For the second part, note that $|f_k(x)|\to 2\sqrt k$ as $x\to -1$. Can you see why this gives the non uniformity?

Thereafter, you need to bound the functions independently of $x$ in the range given - where is the maximum value? What is it?

Comment: Because as $k \rightarrow \infty$ , the each function will either go to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$. Thank you ! Any ideas on the 3rd part?

Comment: Be careful for the second part, since $-1$ itself isn't in your interval. I was intending my second paragraph to refer to your third part - you need to bound each $f_k$ one at a time somehow. On the new interval, where is it largest, for $k$ big, and how large is is there?